# rst mode indentation problems (electric indent off)

Tags: indentation

I've turned off electric indent. I am still having serious indentation problems with rst-mode -- making things nearly unusable.

First: I'd like to make all indentation two-spaces. No tabs, not ever.

Next: A *weird and frustrating* thing is happening with directives.

```
.. directive-with option:: option
                           The next line starts here

.. directive::
   :option: something
            The next line starts here.

.. directive::
   :why: would
         :anyone: want
                  :this: to happen?
                         :i-am: going insane.
```

**ALL I REALLY WANT**

I want to press  and have the next line indented by the same amount as the line I was just one. Then, if I want to indent, I can do so, and then *stay at that level of indentation* until I change it myself. 
(I basically want this behavior in every mode, no matter what.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved my own problem**

I realized I Was focusing on all the symptoms and not on the issue I (finally) focused on when I wrote the "All I Really want" problem above.

So -- I bound RET to `newline` + `relative-indent-maybe` -- in programming mode and (just in case) rst mode as well -- I would do it globally, but apparently that has issues for the minibuffer. But now I can just add whatever modes in the future.

```
(defun amw-nl-indent ()
    "new line, then indent based on the previous line"
  (interactive)
  (newline)
  (indent-relative-maybe))

(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'amw-nl-indent)
(define-key prog-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'amw-nl-indent)
(define-key rst-mode-map  (kbd "RET") 'amw-nl-indent)
(define-key rst-mode-map  (kbd "C-j") 'amw-nl-indent)/
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer.